# JavaScript calculator isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, nan

My hourly wage calculator isn't working.  I should be getting 3 different numbers, but the two first numbers don't show up, and the last number is NaN.  Please help.  The code I'm using is shown below.

```
var hourly = $('#txtHourlyWage').val();
var fraction = hourly/60/60/10;
var calc = new Calculator();
function addCommas(str){
    return(str+"").replace(/\b(\d+)((\.\d+)*)\b/g,function(a,b,c){
        return(b.charAt(0)>0&&!(c||".").lastIndexOf(".")?b.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,"$1,"):b)+c;
    });
}

$('#year-calculation').html(addCommas(Math.round(calc.annual/(hourly*calc.per_hour))) + ' years' );
$('#your-time').html( (((hourly*2080)/ calc.annual) * 52 * 5 * 8).toFixed(1) + " hours");

$('#txtHourlyWage').bind('keypress', function(e) { 
    if ($('#txtHourlyWage').length < 2) {
        return ( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57)) ? false : true ;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return
})

$('#txtHourlyWage').keyup(function (){

    $('#year-calculation').html(addCommas(Math.round(calc.annual/(hourly*calc.per_hour))) + ' years' );
    $('#your-time').html( (((hourly*2080)/ calc.annual) * 52 * 5 * 8).toFixed(1) + " hours");
    $('#HourlyWageOutput').html("At this rate, it would take you <span id=\"year-calculation\">&nbsp;</span> to earn his yearly income and <span id=\"your-time\">&nbsp;</span> for him to earn yours.");
});
```

This code produces the following:

> At this rate, it would take you   to earn his yearly income and   for him to earn yours.
>   NaN hours

As you can see from above, what the code has produced doesn't make sense because the numbers are missing.  I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.  Please help.

Comment: Start by console.log() for all of your variables and outputs to see where you're losing you values.

Comment: Is there a reason you resetting the HTML for `#HourlyWageOutput` every time you get a keyup on `#txtHourlyWage`? The text there seems quite static, and it may actually be resetting the span elements `year-calculation` and `your-time`, which I'm sure you don't want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with console.log.  How would I use console.log?

Comment: @JaPerk14 - `console.log("Hello World")` outputs `"Hello World"` in your browser's console. `console.log(window)` outputs every single properties.

Comment: This `if ($('#txtHourlyWage').length < 2)` should probably be `if (this.value.length < 2)` because `$('#txtHourlyWage').length` is always less than 2 since you're measuring the number of DOM items in the jQuery object, not the length of the text in the field.

Comment: Ever heard of 80 char lines and white-space? It'll help you write better code and you'll find bugs much quicker.

Comment: I attempted this.value.length instead, but it only made the problem worse.

Comment: @JaPerk14: the [console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) is accessible for a quick read, and seems to be implemented identically (insofar as I can tell as yet) in Chrome as with Firebug (whose API it *seems* to be).

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the numbers on the `keyup` event.

You need to put these lines:

```
$('#year-calculation').html(addCommas(Math.round(calc.annual/(hourly*calc.per_hour))) + ' years' );
$('#your-time').html( (((hourly*2080)/ calc.annual) * 52 * 5 * 8).toFixed(1) + " hours");
```

inside the `keyup`. As it is, they are only fired once, onload, presumably before there is anything to calculate with.

**EDIT AGAIN: Still untested but I think it should work:**

```
function addCommas(str){
    return(str+"").replace(/\b(\d+)((\.\d+)*)\b/g,function(a,b,c){
        return(b.charAt(0)>0&&!(c||".").lastIndexOf(".")?b.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,"$1,"):b)+c;
    });
}

$('#txtHourlyWage').bind('keypress', function(e) { 
    if ($('#txtHourlyWage').length < 2) {
        return ( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57)) ? false : true ;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return;
});

$('#HourlyWageOutput').html("At this rate, it would take you <span id=\"year-calculation\">&nbsp;</span> to earn his yearly income and <span id=\"your-time\">&nbsp;</span> for him to earn yours.");

$('#txtHourlyWage').keyup(function (){

  var hourly = $(this).val();
  var fraction = hourly/60/60/10;
  var calc = new Calculator();

  $('#year-calculation').html(addCommas(Math.round(calc.annual/(hourly*calc.per_hour))) + ' years' );
  $('#your-time').html( (((hourly*2080)/ calc.annual) * 52 * 5 * 8).toFixed(1) + " hours");
});
```

Of course, you don't need to set `$('#HourlyWageOutput')` if it's already defined in the HTML.

Comment: i think the basic problem is that you need to be doing all this calculation inside the `keyup` event. That includes grabbing the `hourly` variable, calculating its fraction, etc. At the moment that stuff is calculated on page load, and every time the `keyup` is fired, it still refers to those original variables.

Comment: I also attempted your solution, but still didn't get the output I was looking for.

Comment: I don't suppose you could make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? The code is written kinda densely to make for easy reading. Try stripping out all the unnecessary stuff, put it in a fiddle, and we'll go from there.